# Handling Large amounts of data and Requesting API's

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

I have a lot of postcodes (over 12,000) and need to request these from an API and save the response.

My current solution is to request them all individually but python returns 
`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded during compilation` 
and there are over 37,000 lines.

I am looking for a simpler way to request all of the postcodes and save the response.

Below is the code for requesting one postcode at a time and saving it

The postcodes are stored in an Excel Spreadsheet.

```
# Import Libraries
import urllib.parse
import requests
from datetime import datetime

# Call the API
main_api = 'https://doitonline.york.gov.uk/BinsApi/EXOR/getWasteCollectionsForPostCode?'
postcode = "YO1 6EH"

url = main_api + urllib.parse.urlencode({'postcode': postcode})

json_data = requests.get(url).json()

print(json_data)
now = datetime.now()

saveFile = open("test"+str(now)+".txt", "w")
saveFile.write(str(json_data))
saveFile.close()
```

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Which lines throws this Exception ? You're using a loop ? Because there is no point of recursion in your code nor your goal

Comment: No line throws an exeption, the program will not even run in IDLE. That error is given when running in Terminal.

Comment: This exact code ?

Comment: That is the smaller code, which only does one postcode. This is the full code https://pastebin.pl/view/9dedffd9

Comment: Yeah, I don't really know any other way. I mainly code in swift, but need JSON data for the app, so went to python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hum, you may never create as many variable as you have here. If you over 30-40, you really should think different, so 36000 ...

---

So, now :

1. Store all the post code in a text file `"postCodes"`, one by line
2. Open the file, and loop over the post code to make the request and save the result in an output file `"test" + str(now) + ".txt"`

```
main_api = 'https://doitonline.york.gov.uk/BinsApi/EXOR/getWasteCollectionsForPostCode?'
now = datetime.now()

with open("postCodes") as postcodes,\ 
     open("test" + str(now) + ".txt", "w") as saveFile:

    for postcode in postcodes:
        postcode = postcode.rstrip()
        url = main_api + urllib.parse.urlencode({'postcode': postcode})
        json_data = requests.get(url).json()
        saveFile.write(str(json_data) + "\n")
```

Comment: What is this code doing? Test is the text file containing the JSON output, not the postcodes?

Comment: I have put all the post codes in a text file called postCodes but the program returns the error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'postCodes'`

Comment: @benl134 The error is pretty explicit no ? The file is not where the code is run, do `print(os.path.abspath('.'))` to find you where your are, OR use an absoluta path

Comment: The file is in the same folder as the code and `print(os.path.abspath('.'))` returns the correct location

Comment: @benl134 Debug with `os.path.exists("postCodes")` and `os.listdir()` to find where the file is

Comment: Using `os.path.exists("postCodes")` and `os.listdir()` returns blank

Comment: @benl134 don't understand how you run your code, os, you may have something, or did you use a print around these 2 methods ? You should leanr jpython a bit more I guess

Comment: There were two issues,
The file was saved as a .rtf file, and after renaming, 
`with open("postCodes.txt") as postcodes, open("jsondata.txt", "w") as saveFile:`
You had to add .txt after the postCodes, thank you for helping